# Access two elements in a for loop

Tags: julia

What is a quick way to get two neighboured elements when looping through a for loop in Julia?

Suppose I have

```
z = linspace(1, 10, 9)
for i in z[1:length(z)-1]
    println(i, " ")
end
```

Can I somehow get both elements `i` and the next one `i+1`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Since it is common, a special iterator has been defined in `IterTools.jl` for just this kind of task. The other special iterators are also very useful (from personal experience) and worth studying.

```
using IterTools  # Pkg.add("IterTools")
z = range(1,10,9)
for (v1,v2) in partition(z,2,1)
    @show v1,v2
end

##(v1, v2) = (1.0, 2.125)
##(v1, v2) = (2.125, 3.25)
##(v1, v2) = (3.25, 4.375)
##(v1, v2) = (4.375, 5.5)
##(v1, v2) = (5.5, 6.625)
##(v1, v2) = (6.625, 7.75)
##(v1, v2) = (7.75, 8.875)
##(v1, v2) = (8.875, 10.0)
```

The parameters `2,1` of `partition` are the size and step of the tuples.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to Julia [Doc](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/collections/#collections-and-data-structures), The general `for` loop in Julia:

```
for i = I   # or  "for i in I"
    # body
end
```

Is translated into a `while` structure:

```
state = start(I)
while !done(I, state)
    (i, state) = next(I, state)
    # body
end
```

So, using the same syntax, one could simply implement custom & efficient loops, e.g. the following one that in each iteration extracts two neighboring elements:

```
I=linspace(1, 10, 9)
state = start(I)
while !done(I, state)
  (i, state) = next(I, state) # 
  (j, _)     = next(I, state) # extract next element without update state
  println(i,' ',j)
end
#= >
1.0 2.125
2.125 3.25
3.25 4.375
4.375 5.5
5.5 6.625
6.625 7.75
7.75 8.875
8.875 10.0
10.0 11.125
< =#
```

Answer (score 2):

I quite like `reduce()`:

```
julia> z = linspace(1, 10, 10);
julia> reduce((x, y) -> (println("$x + $y = $(x+y)"); y), z)
1.0 + 2.0 = 3.0
2.0 + 3.0 = 5.0
3.0 + 4.0 = 7.0
4.0 + 5.0 = 9.0
5.0 + 6.0 = 11.0
6.0 + 7.0 = 13.0
7.0 + 8.0 = 15.0
8.0 + 9.0 = 17.0
9.0 + 10.0 = 19.0
10.0
```

The idea is for the function to leave behind the second value so that it can be used as the first value of the next pair.

You can go backwards if you use `foldr()` and return the first value:

```
julia> foldr((x, y) -> (println("$x + $y = $(x+y)"); x), z)
9.0 + 10.0 = 19.0
8.0 + 9.0 = 17.0
7.0 + 8.0 = 15.0
6.0 + 7.0 = 13.0
5.0 + 6.0 = 11.0
4.0 + 5.0 = 9.0
3.0 + 4.0 = 7.0
2.0 + 3.0 = 5.0
1.0 + 2.0 = 3.0
1.0
```